# How to implement a horizontal image effects/filters view in android?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, android-imagebutton

I am trying to implement an image effects/filters preview in an android app.

Example [From CamScannner App]:

[image]

How do I implement the stack of horizontal image filter previews in android as shown in the example [Auto/Original/Lighten/Magic/Gray]? Note: I am not asking about the implementation of the filters. I would like to know how to render.

I tried:

https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow

But I am looking for a simple horizontal stacking.

Comment: You can use customized `TabLayout` where swipe has been disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so it would be much of work. You just have to use `RecyclerView` with horizontal `LinearLayout` I can just guide you here.

Once user take the image or select the image. You need to find a way to give that image to `RecyclerView`'s `adapter` Inside then adapter. You just apply the respected filter to the image and return the image to `ViewHolder`. Simple it is. If you need more descriptive answer just let me know.

Comment: I will really appreciate a working example. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I will provide you a demo on weekend.

Comment: Meanwhile, I found this: http://whats-online.info/science-and-tutorials/87/Android-tutorial-Horizontal-RecyclerView-with-images-and-text-example/

thanks anyways!

Comment: Exaclty that's what you needed

Comment: @ssk have you find that, I am exactly want this type of filter.